# How do I move data from one column to another in Python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are Five columns in the DataFrame 'Product', 'Type', 'Rating', 'Reviews' and 'Category'.

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
  Product    Type     Rating  Reviews    Category 
1  'A'      'Free'     5       10         1
2  'B'        2       19        3         NaN
3  'C'      'Free'     3       15         1
4  'D'      'Paid'     4       20         2
```

I want to modify only rows that contain NaNs. In my case I need to move only the values in Index 2 (Row 2) by keeping the other indexes(rows) values unchanged.

The resulting DataFrame should look like this:

```
  Product    Type     Rating  Reviews    Category 
1  'A'      'Free'     5       10         1
2  'B'       NaN       2       19         3         
3  'C'      'Free'     3       15         1
4  'D'      'Paid'     4       20         2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method `shift`:

```
df.loc[2, 'Type':] = df.loc[2, 'Type':].shift()
```

Output:

```
  Product    Type Rating  Reviews  Category
1     'A'  'Free'      5       10       1.0
2     'B'     NaN      2       19       3.0
3     'C'  'Free'      3       15       1.0
4     'D'  'Paid'      4       20       2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to utilize `numpy.where`, using which you can easily control your data flow.

It might not be the best way, but it's one of the easiest and it's pretty clear what happens here:

```
import numpy as np

(
   df_data.assign(
      Type=lambda df: np.where(
         pd.isnull(df["Category"]),
         np.nan,
         df["Type"]
      ),
      Rating=lambda df: np.where(
         pd.isnull(df["Category"]),
         df["Type"],
         df["Rating"]
      ),
      Reviews=lambda df: np.where(
         pd.isnull(df["Category"]),
         df["Rating"],
         df["Reviews"]
      ),
      Category=lambda df: np.where(
         pd.isnull(df["Category"]),
         df["Reviews"],
         df["Category"]
      )
   ) 
)
```

If multiple columns contain NaNs, you can use the next syntax:

```
np.where(
  (df["Category"].isna()) | (df["Type"].isna()),   # or
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with [`Dataframe.isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html), [`DataFrame.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [`DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
mask = df.isnull().any(1)
df.loc[mask,"Type":]] = df.loc[mask,"Type":]].shift(axis = 1)
print(df)
#  Product    Type Rating  Reviews  Category
#1     'A'  'Free'      5       10       1.0
#2     'B'     NaN      2       19       3.0
#3     'C'  'Free'      3       15       1.0
#4     'D'  'Paid'      4       20       2.0
```

With the mask you can determine which rows has `NaN` values.